# Keeping lists from wrapping around image

Tags: css, list, word-wrap

I'm trying to keep a couple of lists aligned to the left with some text and un-wrapping around an image on desktop/tablet and mobile but don't seem to be making a lot of progress.

Here's the Codepen: http://codepen.io/carlos_serrano/pen/ikjeg

and here the code for what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
<img src="any 100x 100 image.gif">
<h3>Heading</h3>
<p>Just random text here.</p>
</div>

<div class="linkcontainer">
<div class="linkleft">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#unique-identifier1">Left Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#unique-identifier2">Left Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#unique-identifier3">Left Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
<div class="linkright">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#unique-identifier1">Right Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#unique-identifier2">Right Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#unique-identifier3">Right Item 3</a></ul>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
p{
overflow: hidden;
}

img{
float:left;
margin: 0 25px;
}

.linkcontainer {
width: 50%;
padding-bottom: 25px;
clear: both;
}

.linkleft, .linkright {
width: 100%;
float: right;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {
    .linkleft, .linkright {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 30%;
     float: left;
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, what do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: I want to keep the lists aligned at all times to the left with the text, instead of them going under the image.

Comment: where do you want the heading and the text below that to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if I understood your question (and clarification in your comment) correctly, this is what you need to do:

First, move the heading and the text into the `linkcontainer`:

```
<div class="content">
    <img src="http://www.labyrinth.net.au/~toonist/flash_goodies/graphics/image_sizes/rotate_circle_100.gif" />
</div>

<div class="linkcontainer">
    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident deserunt architecto quasi quaerat cupiditate quis harum ipsum ipsa veritatis suscipit iure velit asperiores ipsam vitae reiciendis quos aliquam doloribus repellendus.</p>
    <div class="linkleft">
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Then ensure `content` and `linkcontainer` are both floated left:

```
.content {
    float:left;
    margin:0 25px
}

.linkcontainer {
    float:left;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}
```

I updated your pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aAiqj

**EDIT**: Upon further clarification, there is a better solution that will help prevent wrapping the heading, text and menus on smaller screens: make sure you wrap the 2 main divs into a wrapper div and set the width of this one to the total of the inner divs (plus margins).

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 750px
}
.content {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 25px;
  width: 200px;
}
.linkcontainer {
  float: left;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <img src="http://www.labyrinth.net.au/~toonist/flash_goodies/graphics/image_sizes/rotate_circle_100.gif">
  </div>

  <div class="linkcontainer">
      <!-- ... -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is your newest pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hJbmr

Comment: Thank you Webeno. I see that the lists now don't wrap under the image but only when I have the browser window fully extended. Please have a look at the following image to better understand what I'm trying to achieve : https://scarlos2k.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/wireframe.jpg

Comment: Thank you Webeno. I'm going to do as you say and let you know how it goes. I really appreciate your time and help.

Comment: Hello Webeno. This works great. Any ideas of why the text (<p>) isn't  adjusting to the width of the browser window when re-sized? I'm not sure if the media-query is even working. Thank you very much.

Comment: if my answer helped your original question (not this last one, that wasn't in there originally), vote it up or even accept it as the correct one (big grey check mark), if you have more questions, ask a new question, and you'll have the attention of thousands of others, not only mine... to quickly answer your question: it is because of the fixed width, you may have to have a deeper look into media queries for that to work on different screen sizes, start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Great. Thank you Webeno. I already marked the question as the correct answer. You have been very helpful. I'm new to stackoverflow, so thank you for introducing me to the proper etiquette. I'll keep experimenting with the media queries. thanks again